# jQuery ui tabs : sliding effect when switiching between tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery ui tabs. I want to apply sliding content effect when switching between tabs i.e on showing and hiding of the tabs content. Here is my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jg4r/2)

I'm trying to slide the tab divs with the content in them when I click on the navigation above it all. So Nav link 1 would slide the content of #tabs-1 in front of the screen, etc.

The script I have currently, which has no sliding functionality is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tabs').tabs();

  $('.sub-nav a').click(function () {
    $('.sub-nav li a').removeClass('subnav-active');
    $(this).addClass('subnav-active');
  });

});
```

I've tried to do `slideToggle`, as well as just a `fading out` and `fading in` effect, but couldn't get either to work. So i'm reaching out for some assistance, even if all it is, is somewhere to look, that would be greatly appreciated since i'm not the greatest at javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I don't see where you're attempting to manipulate the tab content in that code.

Comment: That's my problem currently. The things that i've tried I have since removed, because they weren't working. Let me see if I still have an example of what i've tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQueryUI has effects built in. No need to roll your own.

http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9jg4r/4/

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    hide: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

Here's an example with show and hide effects: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9jg4r/5